# Creating tags accidentally

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question recently, and I wanted to add the tag [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits). I started typing it in, then selected it from the list, but something went wrong and I posted the question with just a tag [sugges](/questions/tagged/sugges). And now that tag exists...

What's the process here? How does one create a tag, and how is this moderated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the rep to create a tag, then you can create a question with the new tag or edit the tag into a question, and the tag will be created. That's all it takes.

This is moderated just like any other site activity. Edits and posting both end up on the top of the active page, which others can monitor and fix if necessary.

Note that tags with no questions disappear after a little while, and (at least on some sites) tags with just one question disappear if they don't have a tag wiki.